# How to install 'mnistdigits' module?

Tags: python, mnist

I am trying MNIST dataset, however, the code

```
import time
import mdp
import mnistdigits
```

results in the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mnistdigits'
```

Where I can install this module using pip?

Answer (score 1):

[python-mnist 0.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-mnist) showed up when I googled "install mnist using pip"

`pip install python-mnist`

Comment: I had tried, is not working.  pip install python-mnist is only for "import mnist", not for "import mnistdigits"

Comment: pip install python-mnistdigits
Collecting python-mnistdigits
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-mnistdigits (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-mnistdigits